# Cannot Access To ASP.NET Configuration Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I want to access to ASP.NET Configuration Tool it gives me the following error message:

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
```

What can I do. Is there any configuration which I should set before I can access or ?

I am using ASP.Net MVC4 Project with build in connection string.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should access your `connection string` from `web.config` file before proceeding further.

**web.config file** :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**from code** : access connection string which is in `web.config` file

```
string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```